# How do I skip a blank page of a PDF when extracting text using iTextSharp?

Tags: pdf, full-text-search, itext, invalidoperationexception

My program reads through a PDF and extracts the text.  When it reaches a blank page, I get the error *"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to handle Content of type iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary"*, and the program stops.

How do I check to see if the page is blank before trying to read it?  How do I continue in my program if it does hit a blank page?

Code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
     output.WriteLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    string tmp = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, 
                     new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp))
        output.WriteLine(tmp);
}
```